# C# - Is there a way to deserialize struct serialized in C++ Boost ASIO?

Tags: c#, c++, boost-asio

I am using Boost ASIO as a TCP server networking solution.

Here is how I serialize a struct in C++:

```
struct AccountRole {
    int id;
    std::string name;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & id;
        ar & name;
    }
};

boost::asio::connect(s, resolver.resolve( defaultIP,config.GetConfigValue("AuthServerPort", defaultPort)));

size_t const header_length = 8;
size_t const body_size_b = 8;
std::string data;


ServerOpcode opc;
opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;

Vibranium::AccountRole ac;
ac.id = 5;
ac.name = "John Snow";

std::string message;

std::ostringstream struct_stream;
boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(struct_stream);
archive << ac;
message = struct_stream.str();
message.resize(message.length());
```

And here is how I sent it:

```
std::ostringstream header_stream;
header_stream << std::setw(header_length) << std::hex << opc;

std::ostringstream body_size_stream;
body_size_stream << std::setw(body_size_b) << std::hex << message.length();

data += header_stream.str();
data += body_size_stream.str();
data +=  message;
size_t request_length = data.length();


boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(data,request_length));
```

If it was C++ i am going to deserialize the struct in the following way:

```
   Vibranium::AccountRole ac;

   try
   {
       std::string archive_data(&_packet.body_[0], _packet.body_in_bytes);
       std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
       boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
       archive >> ac;
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
       std::cout << "Error bace!" << std::endl;
       // Unable to decode data.
       boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
       return;
   }
```

However C# does not support Boost Asio and `archive`.

So my question is, is there another way for serializing and deserializing a struct in C# which is compatible with Boost ASIO?

Note that C# will be used for client and C++ as a server solution.

Comment: Take a look at BinaryReader class in C#. I was able to serialize and deserialize binary data between C# and C++. Another alternative is to use gRPC

Comment: What about types in structs like `std::string` which is not present in `C#` ? Is it dealing well with such?

Comment: Strings are painful in C++. You have to know how it is serialized. Most likely it is length followed by the string. You have to know what type is used for length (byte, short, int or variable width number) and what is string encoding.is used. Most likely encoding is be ASCII with 1 character per byte but it can be Wide character too.Find out C++ format and use BinaryReader to read it in C#.

Comment: boost serialisation is only intended for reading by boost serialisation, use a cross platform serialisation like protobuf

Comment: If you are unable to change the serialization, you could consider creating a c++/cli project and do the deserialization in that.

Comment: As Alan Birtles answer, Json is more a standard, and boost is reviewing a json lib at http://vinniefalco.github.io/doc/json/index.html